# Saved image of chart is fuzzy/noisy

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, image, charts, save

I have two MS Charts that I wish to export as .png images. For both I use the `Chart.SaveImage()` method, but with different results. One is fuzzy/noisy and the other looks clean.

Here is the **fuzzy graphic** (later called ChartBHKW). Please note that only the text outside the Chart looks blurry. The legend is displayed correctly.

[image: Fuzzy graphic]

And here is the **normal graphic**, saved as it should be (later called ChartAmortisation):

[image: Normal graphic]

In order to preserve the image size and aspect ratio, the two Charts undergo the following saving procedure: undock, rezise, save, and dock again. Code below.

```
With Main.ChartBHKW
    'Resize and save
    .Dock = DockStyle.None
    .Size = PrintSize
    .SaveImage(JDLImagePath, ChartImageFormat.Png)

    'Reset
    .Dock = DockStyle.Fill
End With

With Main.ChartAmortisation
    'Resize and save
    .Dock = DockStyle.None
    .Size = PrintSize
    .SaveImage(AmortisationImagePath, ChartImageFormat.Png)

    'Reset
    .Dock = DockStyle.Fill
End With
```

I tried with various different sizes and formats. The size has no influence. But it is interesting to see what happens when saved as .jpg or .bmp. Example below.

[image: Fuzzy graphic as jpg]

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly believe that it is related to the **background**, I guess it's `transparent`. Use `white` instead

Answer (score 0):

Set: `chart.AntiAliasing=AntiAliasingStyles.Graphics;`

See [This page](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/64c7d890-c98b-4392-9ec9-1b4af3e24300/labels-bold-when-background-transparent?forum=MSWinWebChart) for details.